# Quartz cron expression

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I need to write cron expression to run every working day at 13:15,16:00,22:00. I managed to write expression to schedule job at 13:00,16:00,22:00, but 13:15 is the problem? Expression is reading from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron expression must be like below

> 0 15 13 ? * *

Comment: 0 0 13,16,22 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *. I dont know how to set first execution time to 13:15